# Causing PostBack after onClosed Event - jQuery Colorbox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, oracle, colorbox

I am trying to get my page to do an actual postback rather than a full reload when closing a jQuery Colorbox window.

Here is my script for doing the Colorbox at the moment.  Note the onClosed function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "40%", height: "70%", transition: "elastic", onClosed: function () { window.location = window.location.href } });
    });

</script>
```

What I want to happen is just throw the browser into a post back so it doesn't lose textbox calendar extender information on the reload.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be lazy, you can call the click() method of some postback element like a button on the page from JQuery. If whatever element you're using is registered for viewstate, it should postback and maintain.

Comment: Also, how would I exactly go about doing that via code.  I'm pretty much a noob at jQuery yet so all information helps.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/ That shows you how click() works. Remember, this will only work if whatever you're changing is in a viewstate tracked field.

Comment: I can't think of any way not to be lazy here offhand. I'm sure there's some official ASP.net way, I just don't know what it is. I guess you could call the main form's submit() as well.

Comment: By the way, why do you feel the need to reload the page onClosed? Are there some controls you need to update?

Comment: Yeah, I have controls on the parent page that I don't want them to lose their values on a full page reload vs. a postback.